# Multiple pages session need to be added together?

Tags: php, ajax

**I have a multi page that records numbers**, I have a session that is being saved as on "submit.php"

```
$_SESSION['hello'] = $_POST['hello'];
echo  $_SESSION['hello'];
```

My problem is that it's replacing the session with only the previous one. How do i make it so they just add up?

For example,

```
<?php
if ($page2 == 2) { ?>

 <?php echo $numbers?>

<?php } else if ($page3 == 3) { ?>

  <?php echo $numbers + $numbers ?>

<?php } else if ($page4 == 4) { ?>

 <?php echo $numbers + $numbers + $numbers?>
```

Is there so that the sessions are being taken from each page and not replaced?

Comment: your question is not related to jquery tag

Answer (score 1):

Define `$_SESSION['hello']` as an array then store your page number to it and retrieve as necessity.

```
$_SESSION['hello'] = array();

array_push($_SESSION['hello'], $_POST['hello']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `sessionstart();`?

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sessionvar = $_SESSION['hello'];
```

Then you can add up the number if you want:

```
$sessionvar = $sessionvar + $number;
```

Then store the new value into the session:

```
$_SESSION['hello'] = $sessionvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php arrays:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $_POST['hello'];
$_SESSION['hello'] = $arr;
?>
```

Then you can call any value at any page by using:

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['hello'][0];
echo $_SESSION['hello'][1];
?>
```